# How to replace section/chapter/subsection depending on the current location?

Tags: sectioning, automation

I would like to refer to the current 'unit' in a section/subsection agnostic way. In other words, I'd like to use `\unitname` in the following way:

```
\section{Foo}
In this \unitname...
\subsection{Bar}
In this \unitname
```

And have it compiled to something like:

> ### Foo
>
> In this section...
>
> #### Bar
>
> In this subsection...

So that the naming remains consistent should I rearrange the contents, change sections into chapters, etc.

Comment: Duplicate of [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345493/getting-name-of-current-structure-level](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345493/getting-name-of-current-structure-level)?

Comment: Yes, I didn't know how to name it, so I couldn't find it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `cleveref` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\Crefname{subsection}{Subsection}{Subsections}
\crefname{subsection}{subsection}{subsections}

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}
\label{foo}
In this \namecref{foo}
\subsection{Bar}
\label{bar}
In this \namecref{bar}

\end{document}
```

[image]